# Do not show Matlab Workspace when function called in C#

Tags: c#, matlab, workspace

Everytime I call a Matlab function in C#, it has to open the Workspace window first. Is there any way to execute a function without displaying the Workspace? Here's my C# code:

```
        MLApp.MLApp matlab = new MLApp.MLApp();
        matlab.Execute(@"cd C:\path\to\folder");

        object BestIter = null;
        object BestPosition = null;

        matlab.PutWorkspaceData("npop", "base", this.Npop);
        matlab.PutWorkspaceData("maxiter", "base", this.MaxIter);

        matlab.Execute("[bestiter, bestposition] = Algorithm(maxiter, npop);");

        matlab.GetWorkspaceData("bestiter", "base", out BestIter);
        matlab.GetWorkspaceData("bestposition", "base", out BestPosition);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try to compile your Matlab function code using compiler.
After that, you execute your MATLAB .exe file in C# environment using:

```
Process.Start("yourfile.exe")
```